# xpath - namespaces - get all parents with name A, from every child with name B

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath, parent-child, xml-namespaces

I need all parent nodes with the name `AX` from every child with name `X`.

After that i need to get the value of the node type.

Im working in Dynamo with Python 2.7 and ElementTree. So i can't use lxml!

**xml:**

```
<main
    xmlns="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0"
    xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
    xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfs"
    xmlns:wfsext="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfsext"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/ogc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0 NAS-Operationen.xsd">

    <AX>
            <gml:node>
                <gml:X></gml:X>
                <gml:X></gml:X>
                <type>a</type>
            </gml:node>
    </AX>
    <AX>
            <gml:node>
                <gml:D></gml:D>
                <adv:type>b</adv:type>
            </gml:node>
    </AX>
    <AX>
            <gml:node>
                <gml:X></gml:X>
                <adv:type>c</adv:type>
            </gml:node>
    </AX>
</main>
```

**code:**

```
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")

path="file.xml"
uniStr = unicode(open(path, 'r').read())
fixed = uniStr.encode('ascii', 'replace')
fixed.decode('utf-8', 'replace')
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(fixed))
root = tree.getroot()

xpathstr=".//gml:X//..adv:[@name='AX']"
xpathchild=".//adv:type"

ns = {"":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0", "adv":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0","gco":"http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco", 
"gmd":"http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd","gml":"http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2","ows":"http://www.opengis.net/ows",
"wfs":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfs","wfsext":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfsext","xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
"xlink":"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","ogc":"http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/ogc"}

parent = root.findall(xpathstr,ns)

for x in parent:
    match.append(x.findall(xpathchild,ns))

print parent,match
```

**xpath:**
I have problems with the first xpath :

```
".//gml:X//..adv:[@name='AX']"
```

EDDIT: GET from all gml:X children the parents with name adv:AX
link:https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
SyntaxError: invalid descendant

**Expected result:**

```
parent=[AX,AX,AX]
```

I need this: match=[a,a,c]

The first two X have the same AX parent. Thats ok, i need a list with duplicate nodes.

Any ideas whats wrong with my first xpath?

Comment: Do you want to get `[a, c]` or `[a, a, c]`? You want to match same element twice?

Comment: I want a,a,c. Not the same element. There are two elements with the same parent. I need a list with same length/number of occurrence of element X.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml input is not valid. Note that AX element should be closed with  closing tag.

AX element is qualified with default namespace which is defined in line:

```
xmlns="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0"
```

Since there is also defined prefix for that namespace (xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0") we can use it later in our xpath.

To get all the parents of node:

```
//adv:AX[./gml:node/gml:X]
```

or the more general xpath:

```
//adv:AX[./gml:*/gml:X]
```

If you want to duplicate the parent node you can use xslt transformation first.

Comment: Sorry for not valid xml! I forgot to mention that there are a lot more nodes than one between AX and X. Your xpath `//adv:AX[./gml:*/gml:X]` doesn't work for me (SyntaxError: invalid predicate)